# Add elements to contentEditable div on KeyUp

Tags: html, contenteditable, onkeyup

How can I add another span in a contentEditable div, every time I press Enter?

Here's what I'm currently trying, and it's not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/ANnMA/

I want another one of those "(Good!)" or "(Error!)" spans to be added for each line in the contentEditable div.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using javascript, cant you just try something like this:

```
if (contentline == good) //however you are testing for good or bad
   $get('CurrentDiv').innerHTML += $get('CurrentDiv').innerHTML + "<span>(Good!)</span>";
else
   $get('CurrentDiv').innerHTML += $get('CurrentDiv').innerHTML + "<span>(Error!)</span>";
```